# Existe como remover um sinalizador?

Tags: suporte, sinalização

Sinalizei por engano uma resposta ([Como fazer push de pasta local para GitHub](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17114/git-fazer-push-de-pasta-local-para-github)). Existe como "dessinalizar?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é possível.

Tem uma solicitação desse novo recurso no metão que pede exatamente isso, entretanto não há planos para implementá-la: [Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/229289)

Se você quer "dessinalizar" pois o autor da publicação fez uma edição **depois** que você ja havia sinalizado, e a publicação passou a ser boa, não se preocupe, pois os moderadores levarão em conta o momento que você sinalizou a publicação, e se concordarem com sua sinalização no momento que você atribuiu ela, marcarão sua sinalização como "disputada".

Se você quer "dessinalizar" pois simplesmente mudou de ideia, não tem muito o que fazer. Elas serão analisadas pelo moderadores e se a publicação sinalizada for considerada boa sua sinalização será marcada como rejeitada.

Answer (score 1):

Como [disse o Math](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1679/74), não é possível. Seu sinalizador pode acabar aceito ou rejeitado por um moderador, ou ser disputado por outros usuários na fila de análise (que foi o que acabou ocorrendo).